# Admin login form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build a login form so an admin I specify in the database can insert images into my database.

I'm having a few errors:

1) I'm using `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` to call itself (call Login.php) so it will load the PHP code below it (which is in the same file). Whenever I press submit, it doesn't go to the specified header in the php code, but rather goes back to the homepage.php.

**Login.php:** Admin Login Form html

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password: </td> <td><input type="text" name="pw"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</center>
```

2) The second issue is... looking at the php code, I'm trying to find a function that will let me grab a specific key of an associate array. For example, I run the database query and store it as an associate array in $result, and return that. Then I want to grab a key ("username" and "password") from users table and compare them to the input from the above html form.

I've tried using array_keys, but that needs an array, not an object. So I casted it, and it still won't work.

I'm using `print_r(array_keys($userResult, "username"));` to see if it would print the key I wanted.

**Login.php** Php code

```
<?php 

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "";
$password = isset($_POST['pw']) ? $_POST['pw'] : "";

$userResult = verify($username, $password);
$array = (array)$userResult; //cast to array

print_r(array_keys($userResult, "username"));

if(array_keys($userResult, "username") == "dan" && array_keys($userResult, "password") == "12345") {
    header("Location: ?action=admin");
}
else {
    echo "<center>Incorrect credentials</center>";
}

function verify($user, $pw) {
    include './scripts/dbconnect.php';

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $pw . "'"); 

    return $result; 
}

include 'include/footer.php';
?>
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to use object $object = (object)$userResult; the you can simply call $object->username; and $object->password;

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest not putting the admin login URL as MySite/Admin or something too easy to find.

Comment: @frenchie good point... and actually, I was wondering if there were any other ways of preventing someone from entering in data if they DO happen to find the correct URL.

Comment: .htpasswd on /admin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave action in blank like `action=""` and it will post in the same page.
I don't remember what `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns inside/outside includes but that must be your problem.

Also, you are alreadly checking the username and password on your query, then you just need to know if it returns a result or dont. Check for the number of rows :)

Comment: lol oh yeah, duh... oops haha. So I should use  'return  mysqli_num_rows($result);' and check if that is == 1?

Comment: Yes, i don't know what your dbconnect script offers, but check if there is a way to do something like $result->rows()

Answer (score 1):

For part one if you want to just refresh the page you can do this.

```
<form action='' method=''>
```

Otherwise it is probably easier to just hard-code the path from login.php to your processing file.

For part two I think you incorrectly created your array.

```
$array = array();
$array[$username] = $password; // $username is the key and $password is the value aka.. array ($username => $password )
```

I am not sure why but it seems like with

```
$array = (array)$userResult;
```

you are trying to set an array as a tuple run though a function and that method seems a lot less clear than just setting the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nimlhug, got it to work as such... forgot my main reason for checking the database was to actually see if there was a matching result... don't know why I was checking again to see if there was a match when I could have just used `num_rows == 1`, lol.

```
                <?php
            include 'include/header.php';
            ?>
            <center>

            <h2>Admin Log in</h2>
            <br/>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password: </td> <td><input type="text" name="pw"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Log in">
                </center>
            <?php 

            $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "";
            $password = isset($_POST['pw']) ? $_POST['pw'] : "";


            if(verify($username, $password) == 1) {
                header("Location: ?action=admin");
            }
            else {
                echo "<center>Incorrect credentials</center>";
            }

            function verify($user, $pw) {
                include './scripts/dbconnect.php';

                $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='" . $user . "' AND password='" . $pw . "'"); 

                return $result->num_rows;
            }

            include 'include/footer.php';
            ?>
```